# instanceof HTMLElement doesn't recognize prototype of HTMLElement created in jsdom test

Tags: javascript, testing, instanceof, jsdom, htmlelements

I try to test a function `recordItemColor` but no matter what I try, the checks for `instanceof` don't recognize the `Object.prototype` type.

I tried a lot, but nothing works. Maybe it is something about jsdom? I would be even happy for other suggestions how to check if the pass target is an HTMLElment or an SVGElement.

Here is the function:

```
import { type StepType } from './handleClickableElement';

const pushStep = (steps: StepType[], step: StepType): void => {
  steps.push(step);
};

export const recordItemColor = (steps: StepType[], target: Element): void => {
  if (target instanceof HTMLElement) {
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(target);
    pushStep(steps, {
      target: target.id,
      color: computedStyle.backgroundColor,
    });
  }
  if (target instanceof SVGElement) {
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(target);
    pushStep(steps, {
      target: target.id,
      color: computedStyle.fill,
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the test:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { recordItemColor } from './recordItemColor';
import { StepType } from './handleClickableElement';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = window;
(global as any).document = document;
(global as any).window = window;

describe('recordItemColor', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    div.id = 'test-div';
    path.id = 'test-svg';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    path.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.body.appendChild(path);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    const div = document.getElementById('test-div');
    const path = document.getElementById('test-svg');
    if (div) div.remove();
    if (path) path.remove();
  });

  it('records item color for HTMLElement', () => {
    const steps: StepType[] = [];
    const target = document.getElementById('test-div');
    recordItemColor(steps, target!);
    expect(steps).to.deep.equal([{ target: 'test-div', color: 'red' }]);
  });

  it('records item color for SVGElement', () => {
    const steps: StepType[] = [];
    const target = document.getElementById('test-svg');
    expect(target).to.exist;
    recordItemColor(steps, target!);
    expect(steps).to.deep.equal([{ target: 'test-svg', color: 'blue' }]);
  });
});
```

My jsdom setup:

import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

```
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = dom;

(global as any).HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
(global as any).SVGElement = window.SVGElement;

(global as any).document = dom.window.document;
(global as any).window = dom.window;
(global as any).navigator = dom.window.navigator;
```

When I log the target at the start of the function, it is not `null`. The node name appears to be `DIV` or `SVG` as expected and when I use `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(target))` it logs the correct type which is a `HTMLDivElement` or `SVGElement`.

I set the type in the jsdom `setup.ts`, which I provide above. Otherwise, the code throws an exception at the check with the error: `Includes HTMLElement.prototype: false`. I found this solution in an issue on the repository of jsdom.

Comment: This is a guess, but `instanceof` checks to see if an object is an instance of a particular constructor function. An `HTMLElement` constructor in one realm is not the same as the same-named constructor in another realm.

Comment: Is there another property of `target` you could use to determine its type?  target.tagName?